# Skin textures way bigger than window itself

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have recently changed the viewport of my UI stage because of another problem and this messed up the dimensions of all elements.
I managed to make all UI elements the correct size again by changing numbers. E.g.

```
Utility.loadTextureAsset(heroImageLink);
TextureRegion tr = new TextureRegion(Utility.getTextureAsset(heroImageLink));
TextureRegionDrawable trd = new TextureRegionDrawable(tr);
trd.setMinHeight(32);
trd.setMinWidth(32);
```

became

```
Utility.loadTextureAsset(heroImageLink);
TextureRegion tr = new TextureRegion(Utility.getTextureAsset(heroImageLink));
TextureRegionDrawable trd = new TextureRegionDrawable(tr);
trd.setMinHeight(1);
trd.setMinWidth(1);
```

This works for tables and individual texture like the one I loaded in the example.

But my main window has a skin attached to it

```
public class BottomMenu extends Window {

    public BottomMenu(Entity[] entities){
        super("", Utility.getStatusUISkin());
    }
}
```

And for some reason the texture becomes really big, while with the previous viewport it was the correct size.

[image: big black bar in the bottom is suposed to be way smaller]

used to be this size :

[image: used to be this size]

Is there any way to scale down the textures of a skin to match the new viewport?

Comment: What is the problem you were fixing by changing your Viewport? Maybe you can use a separate Stage for the UI stuff and the game stuff, and each can have their own viewport.

Comment: I already have a separate stage for UI and game stuff. The problem I was trying to fix was that my UI elements were nowhere to be seen when i used a camera that had a smaller width and height than the screen.